Quel est le sens d'« éléments » dans ce contexte ?
Dans le livre Vite et bien 2 de Claire Miquel (CLE International) j'ai lu  (c'est moi qui souligne) :

Je fais refaire ma salle de bains. Il y a beaucoup de travail : il faut casser le carrelage, changer les éléments...

Je ne comprends pas très bien ce que éléments signifie dans ce contexte. J'ai cherché le mot élément dans les dictionnaires Le Robert et Trésor de la Langue Française. Dans le TLFi, j'ai trouvé

ARCHIT. Éléments d'un appartement, d'un bâtiment. Les beaux éléments d'une construction m'intéressent moins que les précieux vestiges d'une démolition (BARRÈS, Cahiers, t. 13, 1921, p. 137)

mais cela n'explique pas le sens. Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer ? Je comprends que, à part la salle de bains, ce mot est également utilisé pour d'autres parties d'un bâtiment. Pourriez-vous me donner quelques exemples ?

Il s'agit ici d'éléments de mobilier. On emploie le terme pour parler des différents meubles composants l'ensemble assorti des différents meubles d'une pièce, la plupart du temps de cuisine et de salle de bain. Dans cette phrase donc ces éléments pourraient comprendre : un meuble sous lavabo, une ou plusieurs colonne(s) avec étagères, portes et/ou tiroirs.
Ça correspond à la définition 1. du Robert :

Chacune des choses dont la combinaison, la réunion forme une autre chose, un tout. ➙ composant(e), morceau, partie. Les éléments d'un assemblage. Meuble vendu en éléments prêts pour le montage (➙ kit).

et B.2.A. du TLF :

a) AMEUBL. Chacune des parties mobiles et autonomes, en nombre variable, que l'on peut disposer au choix, dans un ordre quelconque, pour constituer un meuble. Meuble à éléments. Classique, traditionnel, ou contemporain, MD offre un choix unique de meubles, d'éléments et de structures qui s'harmonisent et qui permettent à chacun de modeler son propre espace (Art et Décoration, n°199, mai-juin 1977, p. 47).

Toute illustration que je pourrais fournir serait faire de la publicité pour une marque ou une autre, donc je n'illustre pas mais en recherchant "éléments de salle de bain" et "éléments de cuisine" dans un moteur de recherche il sera possible de voir de nombreuses illustrations.
